# Substitutions with regex for different characters?

Tags: regex

I'm generating strings that will be used for the filenames of downloadable assets. The naming conventions of the assets in questions occasionally include forward slashes (`/`). I'm struggling to figure out how to match and replace in the following way:

- If a whitespace is matched, replace it with an underscore (`_`)
- If a forward slash is matched, replace that with something or remove it – still debating on what I would replace it with for legibility. Removing it might not make sense since I would still end up with double underscores.

I currently have this:

```js
const chartDescriptionFormatted = chartDescriptionRaw.replace(/\s+/g, '_')
```

Given the string `Victims / Involved Parties` I'm getting back this: `Victims_/_Involved_Parties` which is human-readable enough, but is not playing nice when I go to download the file. When the file is downloaded, the `/` character seen in the output is replaced with an underscore `_`, so my file names are ending up with a triple-underscore, like so:
[image: A screenshot of a download, showing triple underscore characters in the string generated by the above methods.]

Edit: I realized that removing the `/` character would still, in cases like the given example, leave me with a double underscore. I'm most interested in figuring out how to match different things and replace selectively based on what was matched.

Comment: You could just call several `replace` functions, each with a different regex and replacement, or, you could directly alter the name so it doesn't rely on anything else (like using a timestamp or a UUID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to just call `.replace()` twice in sequence:

```
const chartDescriptionFormatted = chartDescriptionRaw.replace(/\//g, '')
                                                     .replace(/\s+/g, '_');
```

First pass you remove all forward slashes. Second pass you convert any sequence of spaces into a single `_`. The **order matters** in this case. You have to *first* remove the forward slashes.

See demo below:

```js
const chartDescriptionRaw = 'Victims / Involved Parties';
const chartDescriptionFormatted = chartDescriptionRaw.replace(/\//g, '')
                                                     .replace(/\s+/g, '_');
                                                         
console.log(chartDescriptionRaw, '-->', chartDescriptionFormatted)
```

Comment: Could also use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to match non-alphanumeric characters for removal.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not experienced with Regex and jumping into it to solve this one little problem felt like it made more sense to ask for help and then start working on some regex basic fluency. I appreciate your help.